# How can I implement "Expand All" and "Collapse All" using Darren Ingram's Simple Collapsible Panel jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a way to implement "Expand All" and "Collapse All" buttons for use with Darren Ingram's Simple Collapsible Panel jQuery plugin.

http://www.darreningram.net/pages/examples/jQuery/CollapsiblePanelPlugin.aspx

Does anyone know how to evaluate whether a  is expanded or collapsed and based on that answer cause the  to either collapse or expand? I don't seem to be able to gain traction on this one.

Thanks,

Arn

Comment: Have you tried the extensive example code on the page?

Comment: @moonbear. I've tried the code and am using the plugin in an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will toggle all the items:

```
$(".collapsibleContainerContent").slideToggle();
```

This will show all the items:

```
$(".collapsibleContainerContent").slideDown();
```

This will hide all the items:

```
$(".collapsibleContainerContent").slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, Have you tried:

```
$('#COLLAPSEALL').click(function(){
     $('.collapsibleContainerContent').hide(slow);
});

$('#EXPANDALL').click(function(){
     $('.collapsibleContainerContent').show(slow);
});
```

When you click darrens panel the only diference I see is that the display property is changed from block to none, so show and hide should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out tomorrow. BTW, I have three of these collapsible panels on a page.

Answer (score 0):

@Joseph and @rsan. Although I like the plugin and was able to implement it fairly easily, the way to add the required "Expand All" and "Collapse All" functions escapes me and I don't have the time to search thru code for the answer. I've decided on a simpler approach that will allow me to move forward. I like the template found at [LightCMS](http://forum.lightcms.com/discussion/785/expandable-and-collapsible-area-using-jquery/p1).

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.collapsible').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
        });

        $('.collapsible').next().hide();
        $('.collapsible').click(function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        }); 
    });
```

Keeping it simple allows me to write:

```
    $("#idSlideCollapsibleBlue").slideUp('slow');
```

where idSlideCollapsibleBlue is the id of a div located just beneath an h3, like so.

```
    <h3 id="idCollapsibleBlue" class="collapsible" title="New">Telecom: Add New Users</h3>
        <div id="idSlideCollapsibleBlue" title="Telecom: Add New Users">
```

Thanks for looking into thiis. I appreciate it.

-Arnold